# Quantification logic - Is my answer also correct?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I have a problem:

> Analaze the logic of the statements:
>
> ...
>
> (d) Jane saw a police officer, and Roger saw one too.

The answer was:

$$∃x (P(x) ∧ S(j,x)) ∧ ∃y (P(y) ∧ S(r,y))$$

Where $P(x)$ is a police officer, $S(x,y)$ means "x saw y", $j$ is Jane, and $r$ is Roger.

My answer is different:

$$\forall x\exists p((x=j\vee x=r)\rightarrow S(x,p))$$

Where $p$ is a police officer.

Are both answers correct. If my answer is incorrect then why?

**Edit:** where does the downvote come from? It is a mathematics question even though it doesn't seem like!

Comment: If "... is a police officer" is a predicate symbolized with $P(x)$, you cannot convert it into a "name" $p$.

Comment: The question didn't ask for notating police officer P(x). Can't we assume p is P(p)?

Comment: The trick to "minimaze" mistakes is to use the names for "names": $Jane$ and $Roger$. Thus: $∃x(P(x)∧S(Jane,x))∧∃y(P(y)∧S(Roger,y))$.

Comment: @KKZiomek no, it cannot be assumed, for the point of these types of formulas in logic is to make the meaning of the formula unambiguous; assuming things would rid it of its purpose.

Comment: Your proposed answer must be: $∀x∃y((P(y) \land (x=j ∨ x=r)) → S(x,y))$ but this has no the same meaning as the proposed answer, because this one implies that Jane and Roger saw the SAME POLICEMAN.

Comment: Oh, that's why. I didn't realize it. Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is almost correct.  However, you cannot use $p$ to refer to "a police officer".  When you write $\exists p$, that just means there exists $p$, with no further assumptions.  So $p$ could be any person (or thing!) at all, not necessarily a police officer.  To specify that the variable $p$ refers to a person who is a police officer, you need to use a predicate $P$ as in the first solution.  Note that it is further not correct to say "$P(x)$ is a police officer" as you did in describing the first solution.  Rather, $P(x)$ is the statement "$x$ is a police officer".

So let us modify your solution to: $$\forall x\exists p((x=j\vee x=r)\rightarrow (P(p)\wedge S(x,p))).$$

With this modification, your solution is correct.  For values of $x$ other than Jane or Roger, the statement inside $\forall x$ says nothing at all, since $x=j\vee x=r$ is false and so the implication is automatically true.  When $x$ is either Jane or Roger, the statement says there exists $p$ who is a police officer and who $x$ saw.  Since the quantifier $\exists p$ is inside $\forall x$, this $p$ can be different for different values of $x$, so it does not claim that Jane and Roger saw the same police officer.  Thus this has the same meaning as the given sentence.